# rails join table issue with different roles (owner, non-owner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, schema

In my app users can create products so at the moment `User has_many :products` and `Product belongs_to :user`. Now I want the product creator `product.user` to be able to invite other users to join the product, but I wanna keep the creator the only one who can edit the product.

One of the setups I've got in my mind is this, but I guess it wouldn't work, since I don't know how to distinguish between created and "joined-by-invitation" products when calling `user.products`.

```
User
has_many :products, through: :product_membership
has_many :product_memberships
has_many :products # this is the line I currently have but think it wouldn't
                   # work with the new setup

Product
has_many :users, through: :product_membership
has_many :product_memberships
belongs_to :user # I also have this currently but I'd keep the user_id on the product 
                 # table so I could call product.user and get the creator.

ProductUsers
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product

Invitation
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :sender, class: "User"
belongs_to :recipient, class: "User"
```

To work around this issue I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Getting rid of the `User has_many :products` line that I currently have and simply adding an instance method to the `user` model:

   ```
   def owned_products
     Product.where("user_id = ?", self.id)
   end
   ```

   My problem with this that I guess it doesn't follow the convention.
2. Getting rid of the `User has_many :products` line that I currently have and adding a boolean column to the 'ProductUsers' called `is_owner?`. I haven't tried this before so I'm not sure how this would work out.

What is the best solution to solve this issue? If none of these then pls let me know what you recommend. I don't wanna run into some issues later on because of my db schema is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `admin` or `creator` attribute to the `ProductUsers` table, and set it to false by default, and set it to true for the creator.

EDIT: this is what you called `is_owner?` 
This seems to be a fairly good solution to me, and would easily allow you to find the creator.

`product.product_memberships.where(is_owner?: true)`

should give you the creator